# Compiler design - should method calls to intrinsic functions be represented by a different AST node?

Tags: compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, intrinsics, visitor-pattern

I'm designing a interpreter which makes use of the visitor pattern. This interpreter also makes use of many intrinsic functions to help boost performance for common tasks. Up till now, both user defined and built-in functions are bound to the method call node during the semantic analysis phase of the program. During the code generation phase, when the method call node is visited, it will either visit the user defined method's block node, or it will execute the code of the intrinsic function that I have written.

Now the issue I'm having is that this "binding" process is messy. It is simple enough for user declared functions - simply visit the declared methods block. However with built in functions it is a bit more complicated and requires extra information to be decorated into the method call node. So currently, the method call node contains a lot of information, some of which won't be used at all in the case that it is a normal call to a user defined method.

One solution I came up with to this problem was to have a different kind of AST node for method calls to intrinsic functions. This will allow for a specialised visitor method that is specially designed to handle the code I've written for these special methods. However there is a general lack of information on the internet regarding how intrinsic methods should be implemented in regards to ASTs and code generation. For that reason, I'm fearful that I'm overlooking something or that this approach may cause some problems down the road. Thus I'm wondering as to if this is a common approach within compiler/interpreter design, and if not, is there any major problems with following this approach?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable idea if the semantics are entirely different. You may want to make both the user code and intrinsic nodes subtypes of a common type for semantic analysis purposes, especially if the typing rules are the same.

Comment: An intrinsic like GNU C `__builtin_popcount(x)` is a lot closer to an operator like unary `-` than to an arbitrary function call: you may need to expand it to multiple instructions, but it's a pure function.  It's just a quirk of C that it has an operator for negation but not popcount.  Of course, `x / y` might also need to be multiple instructions. 
 (e.g. usually at least 2 on x86 including setting EDX, and many more on machines without hardware div.  Possibly a function call to a helper function, like GCC does with libgcc.)  I haven't built a compiler so I'm only commenting.

Comment: I think this is mainly a matter of opinion. If the interpreter will be simpler by handling the intrinsic functions separately I would do so. In my compiler I handle intrinsic functions as normal functions in the beginning since the difference is small there and separate them later where the difference is larger.